# Some apps (zoom.us) have incorrect scaling on eDPI (1080p) screen but not HDMI (1440p) screen

Tags: x11, display, desktop-environment, i3

I use two screens: my laptop screen (eDPI-1, 1920x1080) and my external monitor (HDMI-2, 2560x1440).

All my applications render just fine on both, at the resolution I would expect, with the sole exception of Zoom (the videoconferencing app) which we use for work. Zoom appears super zoomed in (no pun intended) and doesn't fit in my splits, with all the controls massive and blurry. I'm using X and have had this problem both with PopShell (GNOME) and i3 (which is what I'm mostly using).

I'm not sure if Zoom is a QT app, or GTK, or whatever else, so I don't know if this is a framework issue or an individual app issue, but I was wondering if anyone has experienced something like this and knows how to fix it, perhaps by changing the scaling/DPI for a particular app.

You can see from the screenshots that the controls are way bigger on the 1080p screen than the 1440p screen, proportionally to the resolution.

[image: screenshot from 1080p screen]
[image: another screenshot from the 1080p screen]
[image: screenshot from 1440p screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar scaling issue with xfce on an Arch fork, using Zoom version `5.1.412382.0614`. It seems to be a recent regression though as it does not occur with Zoom `5.0.418682.0603`, so maybe you could try an older version.

Comment: Thanks, IIRC Zoom introduced some backwards compatibility issues recently so I'm not sure I can actually downgrade as I might not be able to join calls. I might try it just to verify the problem.

Comment: Installing the older version did the trick!

Comment: (For reference, if anyone needs, just change `s/latest/5.0.418682.0603/` in the Zoom download URL)

Comment: https://zoom.us/client/latest/5.0.418682.0603/zoom_amd64.deb

Answer (score 0):

I had to set both of these in `~/.config/zoomus.conf`:

```
autoScale=false
scaleFactor=2
```

other things to try:

- `useSystemTheme=true` in `~/.config/zoomus.conf`
- `export QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO=2` before launching zoom
- `export QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS=HDMI-A-0=2.00` before launching zoom
- `export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland` before launching zoom